# How to classify the features instead of rows

Tags: machine-learning, classification, pandas

I have a dataset about some students' e-learning activities and their grades respectively. So in rows, I have the students and in columns (features) I have the activities.

I want to classify the activities instead of the students! Would swapping columns and rows make any sense? (using pandas transpose for instance).

Comment: What do you mean, use the scores to predict the activities? What would you use as your predictor and response variables?

Comment: @Dave I want to classify for instance activty A into class 1, not predict the activity itself. Like saying this activity falls under this type of activities.

Comment: Oh so you mean you would like to group activities together based on features? if so this falls into the machine-learning category of 'unsupervised learning', have a look at the k-means algorithm which has an [easy to use implementation in sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html).

Comment: @Avelina thank you for your suggestion, but I already know what clustering is. It's not the main problem. The problem is even if I do some clustering I don't know if swapping columns and rows in such a problem would make any sense ??